# How to implement uploading multiple photos in one go?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, file-upload

I want to multiple photos in one go. How to implement uploading multiple photos in one go?

Comment: for( int i=0;i<photos.Length;++i ) UploadPhoto(photos[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this several times in the past, and find its a great way to upload multiple images. It tracks the upload progress too:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check below link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prathore/MultipleImagesUpload05122009042335AM/MultipleImagesUpload.aspx